# Ruby on Rails member-basket relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a member scaffold and populated the database with members. Later on I decided to add a basket scaffold (maybe there's an easier way of doing this but it's just an example) so that members can add stuff to their basket for shopping.

The models are pretty obvious:

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :member_id
  belogs_to :member
end
```

and

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_one :basket
end
```

But now I don't want to create a million baskets manually and give a member id for each person. I need a basket created for every member (dynamically - new members get a basket automatically) so that when they access the website they can add items to the basket.

I have followed some Rails tutorial but everything I have come across involves long-winded manual processes that just aren't applicable to anything I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For new members, you can use a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) such as `after_create` to create a basket.

For example:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_one :basket
  after_create :create_basket

  private
  def create_basket
    Basket.create(member: self)
  end
end
```

For existing member, you could add baskets using `rails console`

```
~/Rails/myapp [master] $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
1.9.3p286 :001 > Member.where(basket: nil).each {|m| Basket.create(member: m)}
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this serves as an answer for your question, please mark the answer as accepted :)